# Error while using if statements

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 


bool primeNumber( int x )
{
    return (x==2,3,5,7) ;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std ;

    cout << "ENTER ONE DIGIT NUMBER - " ;
    int x ;
    cin >> x ;

    if ( primeNumber )
        cout << x  << " IS A PRIME NUMBER " <<endl;
    else
        cout << x << " IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

please help me out ..result is same everytime ie 'x' is a prime number ..
also suggest changes ......i m just a beginner so also suggest ways to improve my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( primeNumber(x) )
```

instead of

```
if ( primeNumber )
```

And change your return statement like

```
return x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7;
```

if you want to compare the value.

Comment: thank you sir ..for helping me out and also can u suggest a different way to do this task which might be better because i do found a solution to it but was not satisfied ...satisfied in a sense that it was not properly presented everything was written under main

Answer (score 6):

```
return (x==2,3,5,7)
```

This doesn't do what you think it does, a comma separated expression returns the value of the last expression in the list, you `primeNumber`  method basically always returns `7` which evaluates to `true`.

You have to compare the value with each one, eg:

```
return x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7;
```

In addition, like pointed out by Rahul, you are not invoking the method but just comparing the pointer to the function `primeNumber` to be different from 0, which is trivially `true`.

Comment: Interesting detail! I hadn't thought about comma separated expressions outside their normal usage (ie declarations).

Comment: thank you sir ..for helping me out and also can u suggest a different way to do this task which might be better because i do found a solution to it but was not satisfied ...satisfied in a sense that it was not properly presented everything was written under main

Answer (score 3):

This function always returns `true`

```
bool primeNumber( int x )
{
    return (x==2,3,5,7) ;
}
```

because there is used the comma operator in the return statement and its value is 7 that differs from 0.

I think you mean the following

```
bool primeNumber( int x )
{
    return ( x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7 );
}
```

Also the condition in if statement

```
if ( primeNumber )
```

evaluates also always to true because `primeNumber` is a valid function pointer that differs from 0.

You have to write

```
if ( primeNumber( x ) )
```

As for me then I would write the following way

```
if ( primeNumber( x % 10 ) )
```

because nothing prevents the user to enter a number that contains several digits.

The function can be defined the following way

```
bool primeNumber( unsigned int x )
{
    bool prime = ( x == 2 ) || ( x % 2 != 0 && x != 1 );

    for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i * i <= x; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = x % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir ..for helping me out and also can u suggest a different way to do this task which might be better because i do found a solution to it but was not satisfied ...satisfied in a sense that it was not properly presented everything was written under main

Comment: @Deepak Dahiya See my updated post.